# String to Java object

Tags: java, string

How do I convert the following `String` to a `Person` object ?

### String content:

```
String testString = "John|23;Ron|22;Don|32"
```

### Person  class:

```
public class Person{
   private String name;
   private String age;
   //getters and setters for name and age
}
```

Is there any utility class to convert the testString to Person objects based on the delimiters ";" and "|"

Comment: This look like a job for http://json.org/

Comment: @BadSkillz Except for the part where this isn't anything like JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not in standard format like `json`, so you would need to write your own parser. For example, here is the `Person` class that does what you want:

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static Collection<Person> parse(String input) {
        Collection<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
        for (String s : input.split(";")) {
            String[] properties = s.split("\\|");
            persons.add(new Person(properties[0], Integer.parseInt(properties[1])));
        }
        return persons;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString = "John|23;Ron|22;Don|32";
        System.out.println(parse(testString));

    }

}
```

If it was in `json` you could use a `json` parser.

Comment: Good approach, but this is a case where the two operations (splitting the string and converting each piece to an object) really need to be in separate methods, for clarity and testability.

Comment: @chrylis sure you can extract a method out of the two splits. My goal was to show an approach.

Comment: Does StringUtils split method in apache commons library have better performance compared to String's split method ?

Comment: @pad I haven't used `StringUtils`, but if it uses regex then the performance should be comparable.

Answer (score 4):

Not easily; that's not really a standard format. My advice would be to write a `static fromString` method on `Person`, and then call `Person.fromString()` on each item returned by `testString.split(";")`.

Answer (score 4):

No, you have to write your own parser, because no one could know why to associate the first value to "name" and the second one to "age" - although Reflection could help, but that would be a big overhead for such a task.

For parsing, you could first split at ";" and then for every split array element, split at "|", iterate this array and fill the `Person` according to the array iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This might be done in that way.

```
 public class Person{
      private String name;
      private String age;

        public Person(){}:


       public static List<Person> gerPersons(String personString){
            List<Person> result = new ArrayList<Person>();
            String[] presonsTab = personString.split(";");
            for(String p : personsTab){
              Person person = new Person();
              String personTab = p.split("|");
              if(personTab.length!=2)
                 throw new RuntimeException("Provide proper String");
              person.setName(personTab[0]);
              person.setAge(personTab[1]);
              result.add(person);

          }
          return result;

        }

        public void setName(String n){ this.name = n;}
        public void setAge(String a){this.age = a;}


  }
```